# How to read lines from a text file one by one with Power Point VBA code?

Tags: file-io, command-line, newline, fso

This code will read a line from a text file:

```
set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("c:\number.txt", 1)
text = file.ReadLine
MsgBox text
```

How can I make it read repeatedly one line after another from the same file? I guess, I should use a loop here, right? I need it to read the first line from the file at the first iteration, the second line at the second iteration, the third one at the third and so on till all the lines have been read. How can I do it?

Important addition: I need the code to operate on each line one by one - not all at once!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ReadAll()` method:

```
text = file.ReadAll
```

(Might be of interest: [FileSystemObject Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebkhfaaz(VS.85).aspx))

With a loop:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileName = "c:\testfile.txt"

Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

'' Read from the file
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine

    '' Do stuff to TextLine

Loop
MyFile.Close
```

Comment: The perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you want to use the in-built VBA file handling routines, you would use code like this:

```
Sub ReadAFileLineByLine()
    Dim InStream As Integer
    InStream = FreeFile()
    Open "C:/tmp/fastsynchtoquesttry_quest.txt" For Input As InStream

    Dim CurrLine As String
    Do While True
        Line Input #InStream, CurrLine
        ' do stuff to CurrLine
        If EOF(InStream) Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Close #InStream
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I am quite surprised - it seems that you've been to another question of mine and then came here to share this code. (I guessed it by the first line, which I created by myself and which wasn't here in Mitch Wheat's code on this page.)
   Thank you for this code that you have shared here. It will still take me some time to study through it, but I'll be sure to do it.

Comment: Just a coincidence, I think...I just name subs the best I can, but I'm glad someone else thinks like me! Cool to see you're doing powerpoint vba, it's always interesting when I do that...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference* to the Windows Script Host Object Model, it will help you with the FileSystemObject Object, because you can then say:

```
Dim fs As FileSystemObject
Dim f As TextStream
```

Which will allow you to use intellisense to see the various properties and the Object Browser to explore the library.

* In the code window, choose Tools, References and tick the box beside the library you want.

Comment: I am sorry, it's too complicated for me - I am just a noob. I am sure, though, that there should be some way in VBA, something like realall feature.

Comment: Mitch Wheat has given you the answer, this is additional comments, as you mentioned in an earlier post that you wished to learn VBA. The Object Browser is a great help to learning, as is intellisense.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a VBA routine that reads a text file and insert a new slide for each sentence in the text.

First, in slide #1, add a button that calls the macro named "generate"

Source code goes:

```vb
Const DEFAULT_SLIDE = 1 ' the slide to copy the layout style from
Const MARGIN = 50       ' margin of the generated textbox

Sub generate()
    Dim txtFile As String   ' text file name
    Dim fileNo As Integer   ' file handle
    Dim buffer As String    ' temporary string buffer
    Dim sentence() As String    ' the main array to save sentences
    Dim i, total As Integer
    Dim myLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim mySlide As Slide
    Dim myShape As Shape
    Dim myWidth, myHeight As Integer    'slide width and height


    txtFile = "text2sample.txt"
    txtFile = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & txtFile   'textfile should be in the same Dir as this ppt

    If Len(Dir$(txtFile)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox txtFile & " file not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Initialize array
    ReDim sentence(0)

    'get file handle number
    fileNo = FreeFile()
    Open txtFile For Input As #fileNo

    i = 0
    Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
        Line Input #fileNo, buffer  'read & save sentences line by line
        ReDim Preserve sentence(i + 1)  ' increase 1 more array
        sentence(i) = LTrim(RTrim(buffer))
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Close #fileNo

    total = i
    Randomize   ' for random color

    With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
        myWidth = .SlideWidth - MARGIN  'get width and height
        myHeight = .SlideHeight - MARGIN
    End With

    For i = 0 To total
        Set myLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(DEFAULT_SLIDE).CustomLayout
        'add a slide like slide #1
        Set mySlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(DEFAULT_SLIDE + 1 + i, myLayout)
        'add a textbox with margin
        Set myShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(DEFAULT_SLIDE + 1 + i).Shapes. _
        AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, MARGIN, MARGIN, myWidth, myHeight)
        With myShape
            'add a sentence
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sentence(i)
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 60
            ' color 255 is too bright. Pick a less bright color (200)
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200))
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Shadow = msoTrue
            ' If you want to change the color of the shape
            '.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200))
            '.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200), Int(Rnd * 200))
            '.Fill.Solid
        End With
        'add a textbox for slideshow progress ex) 1/100
        Set myShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(DEFAULT_SLIDE + 1 + i).Shapes. _
        AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 150, 20)
        With myShape
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "( " & i & " /" & total & " )"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        End With
    Next

    MsgBox total & " Slides were added.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Download file:
http://konahn.tistory.com/attachment/cfile8.uf@2175154C573D3BC02A2DFA.pptm